# Multiple httperror sections in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

Is is possible to have 2 `httperrors` sections in a web.config. For example, I have an MVC5 website that is both a front end site and has a simple API running within it. The API runs on normal MVC controllers (i.e. it's not using the WebApi).

I want to have a `httperrors` node to handle the front end and another specifically to handle the API errors.

FYI - The API is within an `Area` of the site.